# Applescript to copy selected word and definition to Notes

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm learning a new language and find myself using the "look-up" functionality in MacOS quite often. I'd like to log all word look-ups I do and their definition using the built-in dictionary application in MacOS. There are a few other posts on the topic but they didn't seem to work for me. Here are my requirements:

1. Use the French language dictionary for word definitions
2. Save the word and word definition to a specific Note (in the Notes app) so it's synced across all devices

Following other posts etc. I've come up with the below script that I'm using in Automator as a "service" (with its shortcut key defined in System Preferences):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    set lookUpWord to quoted form of (input as string)
    set wordDefinnition to do shell script "open dict://" & lookUpWord  
    --This only opens up the dictionary app with the lookUpWord and I don't know how to copy the definition
    
    tell application "Notes"
        tell account "Personal iCloud"
            tell folder "Notes"
                set noteBody to body of note "Word Lookups"
                set noteBody to noteBody & "<div><i></div>" & lookUpWord & "</span></i></div>" & "<div><br></div>"
                set body of note "Word Lookups" to noteBody
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    
end run
```

This script copies the selected text to the Notes application and opens up the dictionary application with the word typed in (screenshot below) but I don't know how to copy the word definition (if it exists). Once I'm able to grab the definition I can add it to `noteBody` as well.

I'm using MacOS Mojave but I'm assuming the script/logic would be OS version agnostic.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You can grab the definition, but it is broken up into different static texts/groups. You'll need a UI inspector like UIBrowser or XCode Accessibility inspector and build the definition from those static text/groups.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any examples you could share- that I could build-up on? I'm very new to MacOs and Applescripts in general. If it doesn't work I might switch to using an online dictionary API instead

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have time right now to compose a good answe, but try this:

```
set wordDefinition to do shell script "open dict://example"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Dictionary"
    set simple to ""
    repeat with nextGroup in groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of first window
        set simple to simple & value of static texts of nextGroup
    end repeat  
    log simple
end tell
```

You should see something like:

```
(*example1 a fine example of a 16th-century longhouse :specimen , sample , exemplar , exemplification , instance , case , representative case , typical case , case in point , illustration .2 we ought to follow their example :precedent , lead , guide , model , pattern , blueprint , template , paradigm , exemplar , ideal , standard ; parallel case ; role model .3 he was found guilty as an example to would-be burglars :warning , caution , lesson , deterrent , admonition ; sign , signal message , moral .PHRASESfor exampletheir teeth resemble those of many mammals, for example, bears :for instance , e.g. , to give an example , to give an instance , by way of illustration , as an illustration , to illustrate , such as , as , like ; in particular , namely , viz. .*)
```

Some new lines, among other things, would help make it look better.